# Find the vectors that have a given projection on the $xy$ plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection

I want to determine all the $x$ vectors that belong to $\mathbb R^3$ which have a projection on the $xy$ plane of $w=(1,1,0)$ and so that $||x||=3$.

I know the formula to find a projection of two vectors:

$$p_v(x)=\frac{\langle x, v\rangle}{\langle v, v\rangle}\cdot v$$

So I have the projection so I should be able to fill that in:

$$(1, 1, 0)=\frac{\langle x, v\rangle}{\langle v, v\rangle}\cdot v$$

Now I consider a generic vector $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and I calculate the dot products, though I don't exactly understand what $v$ is. I know it's a vector that it should be parallel to the projection of the vectors $x$, but not necessarily of the same length.

Any hints on how to proceed from here or if I'm doing the right thing? Should I use any formulas?

Comment: Since $w$ does not belong to the $xy$ plane, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Cesare I think he is looking for those vectors which have the same projection onto $xy$ as $w$. Or he typed $9$ instead of $0$. These are close to each other on the keyboard.

Comment: I think $w$ does belong to the $xy$ plane. Yes, I'm sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean vectors $v$ which have the same projection $w = (1,1,0)$ onto the $xy$-plane:

$$P_{xy}v = w = (1,1,0)$$

So, you look for all 
$$w_t = (1,1,t) \mbox{ with } ||w_t|| = 3 \Leftrightarrow 1+1+t^2 = 9$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: What's your reasoning behind this? Did you use any formula except for the length of a vector formula?

Comment: @Cesare: The projector onto the $xy$-plane just "cuts off" the $z$-coordinate. Algebraically: $P_{xy}(a,b,t) = (a,b,0)$. No further formula except the one for the length of a vector needed.

Comment: If I try to get t out of the equation $1+1+t^2=9$ I get $t=\pm \sqrt{7}$, though the solution on my textbook is $(1, 1, \pm 1)$...

Comment: @Cesare: Then the length is $\sqrt{3}$ and not $3$.

Comment: $1+1+t^2=3 \Rightarrow t^2 = 1 \Rightarrow t= \pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

What you’ve given in your question is a formula for computing an orthogonal projection onto the vector $v$, but in this problem you’re projecting onto a *plane*, so you can’t use that formula, at least not directly.

Think about what it means geometrically to orthogonally project a vector $v$ onto the $x$-$y$ plane: You draw a line through through $v$ that’s perpendicular to the plane and then see where this line intersects the plane. Reversing this process, it should be clear that all of the vectors that have $w$ as their projection lie on a line through $w$ that’s perpendicular to the plane. You know that the $z$-axis is perpendicular to the $x$-$y$ plane, therefore this line can be given parametrically as $v = w+t(0,0,1)$. Set the length of this vector to $3$ and solve for $t$.